# I can't display the data send from backend in the front end

Tags: node.js, mongoose, handlebars.js

I'm creating a URL shortening app. And i wanna to display the created URLs in the front-end. I'm using express in backend and hbs as the view engine. I have sent the data fetched from the database as follows

```
router.get('/', ensureAdmin, async (req, res) => {
  const shortUrls = await ShortUrl.find()
  console.log(shortUrls)
  res.render('app', {shortUrls})
})
```

The console view of `shortUrl` is looks like

```
[
  {
    clicks: '0',
    _id: 5fb9399f5afe75762a533948,
    fullUrl: 'instagram.com/dev_thakku',
    slug: 'ig',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    clicks: '0',
    _id: 5fb93a47d455a878e471ee7b,
    fullUrl: 'amazon.com/something',
    slug: 'amazon',
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

And my handlebars (hbs) code as follows

```
{{#each shortUrls}}
      <h1>{{this.fullUrl}}</h1>
      <h1>{{this.url}}</h1>
      <h1>{{this.clicks}}</h1>
{{/each}}
```

But no data is showing in the front-end. Somebody please help me to fix this issue.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Do you receive anything on your client side?  Check by looking in the network tab of your console. Maybe you should JSON_stringify your shortUrls before sending it from the backend.

Comment: @fqrd Sorry I can't check that. Because I'm coding it from my mobile phone.